# Add product to cart for user - WC()->cart->add_to_cart

Tags: php, functions, woocommerce-offtopic

I'm trying to add a product to the cart for a user. I am using `WC()->cart->add_to_cart`. But it's not working, I checked docs, but nothing found there,

I just wanted to add to cart product on specific user id.

Comment: Please elaborate on 'Not working'. Does nothing happen? Does it throw an error. And please add a bit more of your code. So it's for one specific user that you're trying to do this?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to add an item to the cart of a specific user, not just the session of the browser making the request. WooCommerce's `add_to_cart` function will only add an item to the cart of the user making the request.

I don't believe WooCommerce has an easy one-line solution, but you could make your own function. There's a pretty good example in this answer for updating a user's cart using user meta: [Add Products to user's ID Woocommerce](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/334774/add-products-to-users-id-woocommerce)